# VBA Macro not working even when using the portions that don't require Adobe

Tags: excel, vba

I have my large user form "program" in vba and I can use it just fine. one part of the program requires "Adobe Acrobat 10.0 type Library" but most of my team won't interact with that part

However when my team access the parts that don't require Adobe Acrobat it still shows the Error that it can't find the library. What can I do to stop vba from looking for a missing library that it is not using.

Things that trigger this so far are below... there may be more I am not aware of.

`Date`

`Today()`

`Left()`

`Right()`

`Format()`

I would prefer not to rework my code if i could just stop it from looking for the Adobe Library but why does this trigger?

Comment: one solution (maybe) is late-referencing. Instead of dimming adobe objects directly (I don't know what objects you are using ... lets say it is an ADOBE.Document), then instead of `Dim doc as ADOBE.Document` you instead `Dim doc as Object` and later when you assign it you assign it with a statement like `set doc = CreateObject("ADOBE.Document")` So that MIGHT help.

Comment: From what you are saying it also seems possible that some of your adobe functionality is invoked when the spreadsheet is calculated ... in which case ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ maybe need further isolate the use of this library.

Comment: Your errors are being triggered because the VBA compiler is coming across statements that reference an Adobe Acrobat type. If that library is missing from the references (`Tools->References`) you will always end up with errors regardless of whether that section of code is used or not. As @topsail suggested, you can try late referencing. The only other alternative would be to make that library available to all your users.